# <200b></200b> weird sign in string - how to remove it

Tags: python, unicode

I have these weird `<200b></200b>` signs in my strings. What is it and how can I remove it? It seems to just be whitespace

```
You appreciate traditional values â€‹â€‹and expect respect
```

`â€‹â€‹` is how it displays when I look at it in console.

Comment: That's probably the unicode code point for a [zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm), but could you show us some sample code?

Comment: @Beri yep, file is being written into a file

Comment: @Dannnno added the string to question

Comment: Do you want to remove it or escape it? Your question body and title are inconsistent

Comment: @Dannnno I want to remove it, because I think, It doesnot take any space (zero width space) in string anyways so I can remove it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove it, you can normalize it with [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html)...

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'Goodbyeâ€‹â€‹Garbage').encode('ascii', 
    'ignore')
'GoodbyeGarbage'
>>>
```

Note that this simply returns a ASCII string, and you don't have unicode after using this technique.

Another option that only works with the example you provided...

```
>>> u'Goodbyeâ€‹â€‹Garbage'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'GoodbyeGarbage'
>>>
```

Adding [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) gives you more flexibility to deal with strange cases and decompose them to real ASCII, but a raw `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` will strip out all unicode characters without trying to normalize them first.